# Que veut dire « guidounage » ?

Tags: sens, québec

C'est un mot rencontré dans la presse québécoise. Le sens n'est pas évident pour moi. J'ai pensé à bricolage mais je n'en suis pas sûre.
Je ne l'avais jamais rencontré en français de France.

Comment: Vu le sens de [guidoune](http://www.laparlure.com/terme/guidoune/), je pense plutôt au racolage ou au pavoisement. Comme je ne connaissais pas le mot non plus, je laisse un natif confirmer ou infirmer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Comme Gilles l'indique, « guidounage » vient de « guidoune », qui signifie généralement racoleuse, qui recherche des faveurs, et même exhibitionniste. Dans un certain sens, « tramp » pourrait être un bon équivalent anglais. Guidouner/guidounage est l'action d'être une guidoune, se rabaisser pour obtenir ce que l'on veut, si je puis dire.

Answer (score 0):

Non non guidouner en bon québécois veut dire sortir beaucoup..on dit souvent arrête de guidouner...arrête de sortir

Comment: Dans ce contexte, *sortir* n'a rien à voir avec les autres sens ? Voici le [tour] du site et le [help] pour faciliter les réponses, et bienvenue sur French Language SE.